# how to show an info window without showing the icon of a marker in google map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Can I show only the info window in google map? I am developing an Android app with Google Map's V2 api. I wanted to show the route information in a info window, but I don't want to show the marker icon. So can info window be separated from a marker? If so how can I only display the info window while hiding the marker.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow it would be interesting to do so. I don't know if you can  do that without a marker.

because the documentation of google says something like this:

[Google Maps for Android V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)

> ```
>     An info window allows you to display information to the user when they tap on a marker
>  on a map. By default, an info window is displayed when a user taps on a marker if the
>  marker has a title set. Only one info window is displayed at a time. If a user clicks on
>  another marker, the current window will be hidden and the new info window will be
>  displayed. You can show an info window programmatically by calling showInfoWindow() on the
>  target marker. An info window can be hidden by calling hideInfoWindow().
> ```

But you can trick out one thing, just try to place a **transparent** marker image as a **resource** using code:

```
Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                     .position(latLng)
                     .title("Title")
                     .snippet("Snippet")
                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                     .fromResource(R.drawable.marker))); // transparent image

marker.showInfoWindow();
```

over `R.drawable.marker` use your **own marker** which will be a transparent one.

**Edit:**

And beside this i am sure if you want to display your route information in that info window that you should use a **custom infowindow**

You can create your own custom `infowindow` using a `XML` or just using an image.

**link:**

[custom infowindow](http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html)

[small tutorial on android custom infowindow](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html)

Hope this help you.

Do let me know if that works out for you, eager to know your response.

Thank you.

Comment: That's interesting. will definitely try that! Thanks for your suggestion @Ankxx13. As a side note, I was wondering if this can only be achieved by info window. My intention is to show the info about a route segment, Do you see any other UI components in Android potentially usable for this scenario?

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was really helpful

Answer (score 9):

You can assign the opacity of the marker to 0.

I combined @Xingang answer to achieve more better result.

```
marker.setAlpha(0.0f);
marker.setInfoWindowAnchor(.5f,1.0f);
```

Comment: Great tip! Although I noticed that the info window disappears after tapping anywhere on the map, and I came up with the following add-on to keep it on: `map.setOnMapClickListener(ignored -> marker.showInfoWindow())` (the listener anonymous inner class is simplified using retrolambda here).

Answer (score 2):

I was too lazy to use a transparent image as the icon, and I want to show the icon for some cases and hide it for other cases. So I moved the position of the info window lower to hide the icon.

```
marker.setInfoWindowAnchor(.5f, 1.0f);
```

BTW, marker.setVisible(false) doesn't work, because it hides the info window as well.