# How to remove marker icon

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I've got a marker with info window. How can I remove that green finger from the map? Look at this:

[image]

My code:

```
Marker startMarker = new Marker(mapView);
startMarker.setPosition(gPt);       
startMarker.setIcon(null);//doesn't help
startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, 1.0f);
InfoWindow infoWindow = new MyInfoWindow(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble,
        mapView, company);
startMarker.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);
startMarker.setTitle(company.getName());
startMarker.showInfoWindow();           
mapView.getOverlays().add(startMarker);
```

Comment: replace marker icon with transparent one

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20031319/1479511)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
mapView.getOverlays().remove(startMarker);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: mapView.getOverlays().remove(startMarker);
        mapView.invalidate();

Comment: I want just get rid of green finger, not the marker. If I remove marker, map won't show me info window probably

Answer (score 2):

Understanding you want to show the infowindow, but without any marker icon: replace the default "green finger" marker by a small transparent icon.

- Small (1x1 px), so that your InfoWindow sticks to the gPt position.
- Transparent so that the user see nothing.

  startMarker.setIcon(mySmallTransparentIcon);